# Find a formula for... (Induction and Recursion)

Tags: induction

a)Find a formula for

$$\frac 1 2 + \frac 1 4 + \frac 1 8 + \cdots + \frac1{2^n}$$

by examining the values of this expression for small values of $n$.

b) Prove the formula you conjectured in part a.

If you can help me with part a, I would really appreciate it. I know how to prove it. I just can't find a formula to the first question.

Thanks.

Comment: You should have included the result of "examining the values of this expression for small values of $n$", which I assume is something you've done already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac12&=\frac12=1-\frac12\\
\frac12+\frac14&=\frac34=1-\frac14\\
\frac12+\frac14+\frac18&=\frac78=1-\frac18
\end{align*}$$

Comment: There's a typo in the very first equality.

Comment: @GitGud: Thanks; fixed. (You were supposed to do a somersault while reading it!)

Comment: Ahahah, good one.